# Adding Google Analytics tracking code to product links in abandoned cart email

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, email-templates

I am a Magento newbie and I am not much of a PHP guy either.

I am setting up abandoned cart emails in our magento site and it uses Abandoned Carts Pro extension to generate these abandoned cart tables. I want to change the format of the mail that would be sent, and I can't seem to understand how the email variables work.

Right now, the template at `app/locale/en_US/template/email/abandoned_cart.html` looks like this:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650">
    <tr>
       <td valign="top">
          <p><strong>Hello {{var customer_name}},</strong></p>
          <p>Thank you for stopping by {{var website_name}} and considering us for your purchase. We noticed that during your visit to our store you placed the following item(s) in your shopping cart, but did not complete the transaction.</p>
          <p>Shopping Cart Contents: </p>
          <p>{{var products}}</p>
```

I want to add a tracking code to the product link that comes from `{{url products}}` and I don't know where this code is being generated or how to change it. I have tried changing the product code to look like this, to check if any of these variables work:

```
      <p>Shopping Cart Contents: </p>
      <p>{{var products}}</p>
      <p>{{var product_name}}</p>
      <p>{{var product_url}}</p>
      <p>{{var product_image}}</p>
      <p>{{var product_url}}?utm_source=abandoned_cart&utm_medium=email</p>
```

but the variables are not working like the [reference](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/system_email_template/index) suggests. All I end up getting are empty `<p>` tags with the analytics text.

How can I add the tracking code to product urls that would get generated?

Comment: template variables are set before sending the e-mail, check the controller or model or block of the module.

Comment: @Pankaj: Sorry for being ignorant, but could you tell me where should I be looking for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out myself, and wanted to post the answer. Also answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27633218/1076075).

The code that generates the `products` is in the models of the third-party extension I've installed for sending the cart emails. I have too many extensions installed, and couldn't find this one easily.

I understood that all the extension related code is in `app/code/local/<extension-name>/Cartalert`. (the Cartalert directory would be named differently depending on the extension). I did this by `grep`ing through my repository searching for "Save and Send out" text, which is used in CMS for manually sending these emails.

```
grep -Ril "Save and Send out" <directory>
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16956810/1076075) was my reference. Also, if you're dealing with custom emails like me, [this](https://www.ashsmith.io/2014/08/28/custom-transactional-emails-in-magento/) would help.

Next I went to the model where these alerts are being generated, which was in `app/local/<extension-name>/Cartalert/Model/Cartalert.php`

This was the relevant code I had to change.

```
for ($i=0, $n=sizeof($prod); $i<$n; $i+=2){
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->setStoreId($this->getStoreId())
                ->load($prod[$i]);
            if(in_array($product->getStatus(),$status)&&in_array($product->getVisibility(),$visibility)&&$product->isSaleable())
            {
                $url = $baseUrl . 'catalog/product/view/id/'.$prod[$i];
                $name = $prod[$i+1];
```

I had to append the parameters to the `$url` string, and it got the job done. Never thought `grep` would help me more than the docs... :D